# Codeigniter | OVH | htaccess / url rewriting | Site very slow

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

Here is my htaccess for removing the index.php with codeigniter :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

But with this .htaccess, there is an error "File not found."
So, I'm searching, and here is a little solution : http://forum.ovh.com/showthread.php?93572-Codeigniter-et-htaccess

Adding a "?" resolve the problem, but the site is sometimes very very slow, and sometimes very fast ! And sometimes, my style sheets don't load (assets/css/)...

What is the problem ? I think it's the htaccess but I'm not sure.

spec.:
Host : OVH
php ver. : 5.2
CI ver. : 2.1.4

Comment: No, but what is the problem with https ?
I've tested with an other server and it's working without https

Answer (score 2):

Try this code from the [OVH Forum](http://forum.ovh.com/showthread.php?93572-Codeigniter-et-htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: If you share a piece of code like this, pleas explain what it does here instead of just linking.

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
            RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
            RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you but seem like the same effect :/

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

write this in your htaccess 
check this link to enable mod_rewrite function of [apache setting](http://www.leonardaustin.com/blog/technical/enable-mod_rewrite-in-xampp/)

Comment: Thank you, it's faster, but I don't have access to the apache settings :(
So only the index page is ok, and the style sheets, images, js too.
Others pages (other controllers) are not ok, with the "File not found." message

Comment: Ops I missed it I suppose

Comment: @user3768981 which is your server