# File not Found Codeigniter in production

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

So I've put my website online and only my landing page (Home_controller) is working fine but any other page is not working.

`http://www.my-websiteabc.net/` works fine but not `http://www.my-websiteabc.net/About_cookies`

`http://www.my-websiteabc.net/Home_controller` and `http://www.my-websiteabc.net/home_controller` don't work either.

I've spent all day reading different suggestions and workarounds but can't get it to work.

What I've tried so far:

1.My Controllers filenames and Classes have a first Uppercase character. For instance:

- About_cookies.php
- class About_cookies extends CI_Controller
- View: cookies.php

2.My folder structure is:

```
/.
   /my-websiteabc
   /my-websiteabc/application
   /my-websiteabc/js
   /my-websiteabc/css
   /my-websiteabc/system
```

3.I have .htaccess in the root folder contains:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

4.I also tried with/without this .htaccess in the application folder:

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

5.My routes.php :

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Home_controller';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

6.And config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.my-websiteabc.net/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

I get `File not found.` when trying anything else than `http://www.my-websiteabc.net/` but on this page all the images and CSS are correct so I guess my path is correct.

Using CI 3.1.5 and PHP 7.1.6

**Update 05/07:**

Controller definition (`About_cookies.php`):

```
<?php
class About_cookies extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(); 
        $ci =& get_instance();
        if ($ci->session->userdata('site_lang')) {
            $siteLang = $ci->session->userdata('site_lang');
        } else {
            $siteLang = 'english';
            $this->session->set_userdata('site_lang', $siteLang);
        }
        $ci->lang->load('home',$siteLang);
    }

    public function index(){ 
        $data['main_content'] = 'cookies';
        $this->load->view('templates/default',$data); 
    }    
}
```

The URL my browser is trying to access:
`http://www.my-websiteabc.net/About_cookies`

My view: `cookies.php`

Comment: What happens when you load `http://www.my-websiteabc.net/index.php/About_cookies`?

Comment: With your routes.php on try with lower case `$route['default_controller'] = 'home_controller';` Make sure your file and class and class names have only first letter upper case.

Comment: Please post the code of the Home_controller.php file. At least the class declaration.

Comment: `http://www.my-websiteabc.net/index.php/About_cookies` works fine! I checked with my web hosting provider and mod_rewrite should be available. Can't figure out why it's not working without the index.php in the URL

Comment: Then your .htaccess is wrong. I'll post mine. CodeIgniter works like that by default. Your case is the special case when you do **not** specify which controller you want to load, so it defaults to the one specified in the config file (the `default_controller`).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this `.htaccess` definition:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css|php)$">
    FileETag None
    Header unset ETag
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>

SetEnv CI_ENV development
```

To make it clear, it has three parts:

- The first one is the one you need, will convert `mysite.domain/controller` URIs into `mysite.domain/index.php/controller` automatically and transparently.
- The second part just disables caching for some files. In this case, files with `html`, `htm`, `js`, `css`, `php` extensions won't be cached. This isn't part of your problem, but I think it could be useful to you in some cases (you probably want to remove the `php` extension in order for the CodeIgniter internal cache to work).
- The third one sets the environment for CodeIgniter. It can be `development` or `production`.

Note that this `.htaccess` file should be to the side of `index.php` (the one at the root of the whole CodeIgniter folder tree), not inside any folder.

Comment: Thanks but I get the same symptoms when placing this `.htaccess` at the root of the CI tree (same level as application, css, js, system...). I don't have any `.htaccess` under application, is that correct?

Comment: At least my `application` folder **does** have an `.htaccess` file. It's the same you specified in your fourth item.

Comment: Same thing if I add it back.

Comment: How are you defining your controllers? For example, for a `account` controller, you should create `application/account.php` and it should have, at least: `<?php class Account extends CI_Controller { public function index() { echo "HELLO"; } } ?>`, then the URL with this `.htaccess` should be `http://www.my-websiteabc.net/account`

Comment: I edited my question with the controller definition and the view name.

Comment: found this and it fixed it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375249/codeigniter-ovh-htaccess-url-rewriting-site-very-slow 
I will have a closer look later tonight.

Comment: Hmm... the `RewriteBase` could be the issue. Well I'm not really an expert, but this particular .htaccess works fine on my development server. It's running OS X though, maybe they're a little bit different.

Answer (score 0):

After reading through many many posts, I finally found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375249/codeigniter-ovh-htaccess-url-rewriting-site-very-slow).

The following `.htaccess` works for me:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The thing that makes the difference is the question mark `?` after the `index.php`

I'm not able to say if this slows down the performance yet but I **really would like to know** what this `?` changes. I didn't find any documentation on this topic.