# CodeIngiter redirect error

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, routes

Hi everyone I've been working on a simple php back end based on codeigniter v3. 
i developed it on cloud 9 ide, then i have migrated it on a website hosting.

i changed db configuration file and

```
$config['base_url'] = 'codeigniterfolder/';
```

mydomain/codeingiter/.htacces

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

my problem is about tha the default controller is property loaded  but when i go to another controller it show me file not found , but no errors from codeigniter, simply file not found without 404 error..
can enyone help me ?

Comment: $config['base_url'] is the URL of your website NOT the folder you are using. Example: $config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com';

Comment: Sorry I wrote something wrong in the question, I have set as base URL mydomain/codeigniterfolder

Comment: Do you have files with camelcase names?

Comment: The only one file is a controller called User. php

Comment: But when I run it on c9 it woked

Comment: All webhosting services do not use the exact configuration
Usually it's an uppercase or camelcase causing the 404 error
If you want to confirm, try with only one controller: make the file name and all method names lowercase and test it, if there is no 404 you got your solution

Comment: in routes.php i set $route['register'] = 'user/register';
$route['login'] = 'user/login';
$route['logout'] = 'user/logout';

$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;


$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['default_controller'] = 'user/login'; if i go to mydomain/codingiter it show login correcty but if i go mydomain/codeigniter/register it show "file not found"

Comment: please try by adding base path in .htaccess rule `RewriteBase /codeigniterfolder/`

Comment: i found the answere, it depends on ovh  as in this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375249/codeigniter-ovh-htaccess-url-rewriting-site-very-slow

Comment: thank's every one for helping me

Comment: Your base url is wrong `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniterfolder/';` or live url `$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/';`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
// server base url
$config['base_url'] = 'http://domian.com/';

// localhost base url
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project_floder_name/'; //


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    Options -Indexes

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]



</IfModule>



<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

In config/config.php

We can do Dynamic Base Url

```
<?php 
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['base_url'] = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
$config['base_url'] .= "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), "", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> In Config File

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['base_url'] = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
$config['base_url'] .= "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), "", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

> In Header view File or Common View Add Base Tag below the title and print the Base Url

```
<title>Website Title</title>

<base href="<?php echo base_url();?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue today here is the solution for this problem:

1. go to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` on your vps;
   server
2. add following code in `<VirtualHost>` tag. **I suggest to add at the end**.

```html
<Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Thats all now hopefully it will works
the reason is that your server is not allowing to read `.htaccess` of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `.htaccess` file last line.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```